# Public recognition of SO T-shirts?

Tags: discussion

I just got back from shopping in exciting, cosmopolitan [Wood Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_Green), while wearing my SO T-shirt. Did people in shops say things like:

> You are  a StackOverflow user? Please
>   have this litre of gin at half-price!

or:

> StackOverflow! Do you know Neil
>   Butterworth? He is my God!

Did they b*ggery, but perhaps that is expecting too much in N22. I was wondering if anyone has had positive (or negative) recognition while wearing their shirt? Conferences and trade shows don't count.

Comment: I don't wear it :O

Comment: @Kop are you keeping it in mint condition so you can flog it on ebay for a ludicrous amount in twenty years time?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Maybe it's signed by Jon Skeet and he doesn't want to ruin it?

Comment: I hate revealing my address to anyone I don't know personally, so I never signed up for mine. I guess now I don't have to feel bad that I'm missing out on all the "glory".

Comment: @mmyers This is the sort of thing that gives paranoia a bad name. Utilities, electoral roll, tax man etc. Are you personally acquainted with all of these entities? Anyway, if you don't want yours, can I have it? They've already got my address, and it must be XX large.

Comment: There's a T-shirt now?  Oh well, they probably wouldn't have had one in my size anyway...

Comment: @Neil: I don't think I'm a paranoiac, but I only give out information on a need-to-know basis. (You could find out my first name, age, and general location if you're really good at cyber-stalking -- and even a picture if you're an absolute ace -- but I prefer to stay slightly in the shadows.) Anyway, I also had two other reasons; one is laziness and the other is that I just don't like wearing clothes with logos.

Comment: @mmyers I agree about the logos thing - but these are _free_, which counts for us poor people.

Comment: @Neil: Quite true. And it also occurs to me that they already have my IP (although I use IPs in two different states). Well, if the offer is still valid I just might do it.

Comment: What does a SO t-shirt look like?

Comment: @cambr something like this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/t-shirt-time-beta/45812#45812, but not very.

Answer (score 6):

Still haven't got mine.

[Still sad with no shirt! http://pix.motivatedphotos.com/2009/1/7/633669119863087455-SadCat.jpg](http://pix.motivatedphotos.com/2009/1/7/633669119863087455-SadCat.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, me neither!

Comment: And still none. I'm sad!

Answer (score 5):

I wore mine on a plane once, and while waiting in a long line for the restroom, someone joked that he hoped there would be no "stack overflow".

Answer (score 3):

When I visited a Microsoft office recently, one developer did comment "Nice T-shirt" - but I'm not sure whether they actually knew about the site, or whether they thought it was to do with the general exception.

Comment: It is, after all, an exceptional shirt.

Comment: they probably thought you were making fun of their code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

None at all.

Kinda sad, since I wear it like a badge of honor *and* I live in a high-technology area.

Comment: I'll have to keep an eye out, then.  You've commented twice now that we live in the same area.

Comment: Maybe those t-shirts are just too common in your area?

Comment: @Georg I have yet to see someone with one.

Answer (score 1):

Not the SO T-shirt itself, but I was wearing my unicorn T-shirt the other day, and a guy (programmer) I know loosely noticed it.

> Him: So, what's the deal with that unicorn?
>
> Me: Oh, that's a long story. Do you know Stack Overflow?
>
> Him: Yeah, that's the site where I get all my XML snippets from.

(whatever that was supposed to mean …)

Answer (score 0):

I live in rural Nebraska, so nothing yet.  Maybe I'll wear it when I fly through Chicago O'Hare later this month, so we'll see then.

Comment: Your profile says "WI". You don't live in Wisconsin?

Comment: I know almost nothing about Nebraska except for the Springsteen album. But are there any bits that aren't rural?

Comment: Moved about 6 months ago (has it been that long?) - must have forgot to update meta.  Fixing now.

Comment: @Neil - just Lincoln & Omaha.

Comment: *\*holds up microphone\** Do you have an opinion on the impending realignment of conferences? *(Hey, no one has suggested a SE sports site yet. I wonder if that could work.)*

Comment: @mmyers - Couldn't care less.  The only thing that concerns me is that I'll always be more of a Badger fan.  If Huskers join the Big10 that will make things... interesting in my new locale for a few games each year.

Comment: @mmyers: there is one already.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine ask me: *"How many rep. point do you need to get that?"*

And I answer: *" .. No, no, no.. I had to* ***pay*** *for it, :'( "*

Now at dollar exchange of $12MXN per $1USD  +  shipping, I felt a bit embarrassed for final price I paid.

Comment: Pay? Why? Customs?